# Toggle an LED using timer 2 with an interrupt for a PIC18F6520

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, pic18

I am trying to get Timer2 to flash an LED, this is not the final operation but I had it flashing an LED without the interrupt so I am continuing with this for now. But I cannot seem to get it working. I think I have set up the peripheral interrupts, and the RC2 register so when that equals the TMR2 register the interrupt flag should be set and the interupt should be initiated. When in the interupt I add a delay after toggleing the LED so it will be possible to see the flash of the LED, again not usual behaviour but if I don't add a delay it will flsh to fast and we won't be able to see it.

Here is my code,

```
// PIC18F6520 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HS         // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config OSCS = OFF       // Oscillator System Clock Switch Enable bit (Oscillator system clock switch option is disabled (main oscillator is source))

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = 25        // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (VBOR set to 2.5V)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 128      // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:128)

// CONFIG3L

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MUX = OFF    // CCP2 Mux bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RE7)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVR = OFF       // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage ICSP Enable bit (Low-voltage ICSP disabled)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000


void main(void) {
    
    TRISC = 0x00; // Initialise PORTC as all 0's, LED on PORTC RC2.
    
    // Setup Timer2 1:1 post and pre scaler.
    T2CONbits.T2CKPS = 0b00;
    T2CONbits.T2OUTPS = 0b0000;
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1; // Turn on Timer2.
    
    PR2 = 15; // Set PR2 register to jump to interrupt when equal to TMR2 register
    
    PIE1bits.TMR2IE = 1; // Initialise Timer2 interrupt enable.
    
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Setup peripheral interrupts.
    
    // Run main loop for ever.
    while(1){
        
    }
}

// Interrupt routine.
void __interrupt() isr(void)
{
    // Check to see if TMR2 interrupt flag set.
    if(PIR1bits.TMR2IF){
        PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0; // Reset TMR2 interrupt flag.
        
        PORTCbits.RC2 ^= 1; // Toggle RC0.
        __delay_ms(500); // Delay Toggle to make it possible to see the LED flash.
    }
}
```

Can anyone give advise as to what I may be doing wrong please?

Comment: I would say putting the delay in the ISR sort of defeats the purpose of using an interrupt in the first place.  You should construct your period (PR2) to replace the delay (and interrupt every 500 ms).  ISRs should run very quickly and do as little work as possible.

Comment: What is the timer period? Are you aware that the timer commonly continues to count during the interrupt service routine? -- Please [edit] your question to clarify, and add what you observe instead of the flashing.

Comment: @thebusybee from the datasheet "The Timer2 module has an 8-bit period register, PR2. Timer2 increments from 00h until it matches PR2 and then resets to 00h on the next increment cycle" so I was assuming the timer does keep counting but from 0x00 again once the Comparator has matched the two values, is this not correct? Does this answer the question about the period as the period I guess is when TMR2 matches PR2. It is using an 8MHz crystal, Fosc is then divided by 4, then divided again by what ever I load PR2 with.

Comment: @Jason I am aware there is no need for the delay in the interupt eventually (as stated in the question this is not the final operation), it is only there to slow the flashing of the LED down so I can see it. Eventually the delay will be removed the LED won't flash and the ouput will be on a Pin so I can see it on a logic analyser. This is just a interim code to make sure its not me using the logic analyser incorrectly. Ignoring the delay can you see why the interrupt is never being entered and why the LED is not flashing like the querstion asks?

Comment: Are you sure the interrupt is never entered?  Maybe start by removing the delay and toggle, and just setting the thing HIGH.  Then you will know it at least entered it.  Another *possible* problem is that this is running too fast.  So you can also play with the pre/post scalers of the timer.  I just realized another thing.  You are setting the PORT.  You should be setting the latch.

Comment: So that `PORTCbits.RC2 ^= 1;` should really be `LATCbits.LATC2 ^= 1;`

Comment: @Jason I will look into both those suggestions and get back to you if I am still struggling. Thanks for your advice and help so far.

Comment: Your interrupt is never will be entered because you haven't enabled the global interrupt control bit `INTCONbits.GIE = 1;` . However, even you get into the interrupt, executing a software delay in the interrupts is a software disaster. You should keep your interrupt service routines as short as possible. There are numerous ways of drive flashing LEDs asyncronously without using software delays. Using some of those techniques, theorically you can drive as many LED as you want. To give an example, what should be the period of flashing?

Comment: @Kozmotronik the interrupt is being entered as I have set the poeripheral interrupt register high 'INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;'. I know I should not be using the delay in the interrupt and I will not be in the final code. The final code will not even flash an LED it will just toggle an output on a free pin at hopefully around 500KHz, if I try and flash an LED at this speed I will not be able to see it, hence the delay for the moment.

Comment: See [this demo video](https://youtu.be/TKViX1dKXcM?si=CFqzm07O28TLHvJ4) of a multitasking example. Observe how LEDs are being drived asynchronously without gliching. A whole port is used to drive a basic knightrider with adjustable speed and other 2 pins are being drived with different periods and flashing patterns.

Comment: @Jason I have managed to make it toggle the LED once so I know the interrupt is being entered, and I have change to 'LATCbits.LC2 ^= 1;' and it does change it once but then stays on and doesn't flash. The nmext thing I am going to try is to disbale the interrupts and re-enable once the interrupt has completed to see if that helps it exit and then reset it so it can be run again on the next iterration.

Comment: ***The final code will not even flash an LED it will just toggle an output on a free pin at hopefully around 500KHz*** - Humm I see, but your title says a different thing. I suggest you to point out the real problem well. Just point out your real intention so that we can suggest you the most appropriate solution possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255033/discussion-between-programmasher-and-kozmotronik).

Comment: @Kozmotronik You were indeed correct, upon looking at the interrupt section of the datasheet again I had to have GIE and PEIE set to enable the interrupt. I also had to play with where these two registers where set within my code and it is now entering the interrupt when TMR2 and PR2 are equal.